# JVM crashing while writing to XLSX file( POI)

Tags: java, crash, jvm, apache-poi, jvm-crash

JVM is crashing while trying to write to the .xlsx file. I am using POI(XSSF) for the same.
The error location point in code is the write `method--> workBook.write(fileOutputStream);`

On Console I get..

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0xb68d77f3, pid=14653, tid=1849355120
  JRE version: 7.0_04-b20
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libzip.so+0x47f3]  newEntry+0x73
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in the POI libraries if the error is accurate (enabling core dumps would be useful). Why not just submit a bug report to the project? They will know better how to debug it.

Comment: You could try to update libzip through your package manager.

Comment: try Java 7 update 5 and making sure you have plenty of free space on you drive.

Comment: Apache POI is pure Java, so should never be able to trigger a JVM crash. This looks like a bug in the JVM itself, you'll need to report that to Oracle

Comment: I tried using Java 6 and Java7_05 but the result is same

Comment: Time to report a bug to Oracle then. No Java program should ever be able to crash the JVM, so you've found a JVM bug

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I've found for this, and I've been looking for a while, is to make sure you don't open your `Workbook` with the `File` which you use to open the `FileOutputStream` to save the `Workbook`. Instead, use a `FileInputStream` to open the `Workbook`.

Something like this will work flawlessly

```
        File inputFile = new File("Your-Path");
        this.inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        this.opc = OPCPackage.open(this.inputStream);
        this.workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(opc);

...

        this.outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
        this.workbook.write(this.outputStream);
```

Don't forget to close every opened stream and the `OPCPackage`.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions worked for me.  I only needed readonly access to my Excel files, and setting the readonly flags worked for me:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(file, PackageAccess.READ));
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(file, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `OPCPackage` did not fix the JVM crash for me but using `WorkbookFactory` did. If you look at the [POI Busy Developers Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook) they provide example of reading and writing the same Excel file.

```
File excelFile = new File("workbook.xlsx");

InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Using Apache POI version 3.13, Java 1.8

Comment: [Don't use a Stream if you have a File! It uses more memory](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), as explained in the same page you linked to...

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank you for pointing that out. If I don't use the `InputStream` the JVM crashes. The documentation is just making you aware that it uses more memory, not that it shouldn't be used.