# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code error while editing excel files

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, runtime-error, apache-poi

I am trying to edit excel file using `Apache POI` and `OPCPackage` and it is not working out for me for some weird reasons. Here is the code snippet:

```
File file = new File(basePath, fileName);
int currentColNum=0, currentRowNum=0;
OPCPackage pkg = null;
Workbook wb = null;
if(file.exists())
    pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
else
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
if(sheet==null)
    sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
else
    currentRowNum = lastWrittenRowCol.get(sheetName).getLeft();
for(Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    //some code. This code uses functions like sheet.createRow() etc.
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
System.out.println("before write.out");  //Printed/
wb.write(out);
System.out.println("last statement");   //Not printed.
    out.close();
if(pkg!=null)
        pkg.close();
```

I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00002b517248dae2, pid=14557, tid=47628802967872
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b15
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x4ae2]  newEntry+0x62
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And this is the memory information from the log:

```
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:      5855708 kB
MemFree:       1413996 kB
Buffers:        815896 kB
Cached:        1939120 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:        2339452 kB
Inactive:      1512396 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:      5855708 kB
LowFree:       1413872 kB
SwapTotal:     5140792 kB
SwapFree:      5140792 kB
Dirty:            5556 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     1096860 kB
Mapped:         112944 kB
Slab:           520072 kB
PageTables:      39008 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   8068644 kB
Committed_AS:  2106544 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     51844 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359686179 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

I am using Eclipse. Program was run with arguments `-Xms512m -Xmx2048m`. There is some problem with `wb.write(out)` because statement just before that line is printed but the next is not. (I know I should use debugger but I do not know how to plug it in in eclipse from our build system). Any help appreciated!

Comment: +1 I have observed the same recently. The error occurred in Write method and corrupted the my excel file as well.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh Yup. I have wasted so much time on this. Hope somebody helps.

Comment: Pure Java code shouldn't be able to crash the JVM, so it looks like you have hit a JVM bug. Have you tried reporting it to Oracle?

Comment: @Gagravarr No. I had no idea that it could have been a bug.

Comment: @Gagravarr: I have observed that in case of `opcpackage` and `workbook factory`, the crash occurred, while in case of `fileInputStream` its working fine. I have observed the same in My code as well as in Aman's code both. I am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: No Java code should be able to crash the JVM. You need to report this is a bug to Oracle, so they can fix the underlying Java Virtual Machine bug

Comment: @Gagravarr Ok. Will do it by today. thanks!

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344131/jvm-crashing-while-writing-to-xlsx-file-poi/17329250#17329250)

Answer (score 0):

As the XSSF manipulate the Open XML format, writing it requires manipulation of an archive (zip) .. There are bug in the jzlib ..

Kindly check this fix [JVM crashes at libzip.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405641/jvm-crashes-at-libzip-so)

I hope this could help!